# CSS background-image not showing

Tags: html, css

Nothing shows up when I try to put a background image in a div via CSS. I've tried adding properties like position, width, height. And, I am also able to place the photo via CSS in the `<body>` tag. But, obviously, I'd like to not have to leave it there. Here's my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>

  <head>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>

    <title>
      Lovers &amp; Fighters
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="photo">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul id="main">
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Music</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
          <li>Photos</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="social">
          <li>
            <img/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img/>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#photo{
    background-image: url('../images/bandbanner.png')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging via the console? Is the path to the image correct? Does the #photo div have a height and width?

Comment: What's the `<nav>` tag all about? There's no closing `</nav>` tag. And your photo `div` is an empty container.

Answer (score 1):

The div photo contains nothing, try adding

```
#photo{
    background-image: url('../images/bandbanner.png');
    width: 100%
    padding : 100px;
    //hopefully this will make the photo appear and you can go from there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="photo">
  </div>
```

in your dive you haven't set the size. for example:

```
#photo{
background-image: url('../images/bandbanner.png');
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height & width property of `#photo`.

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ihkawiss/2n0o9t9x/

Answer (score 0):

set your `height` and `width`

```
width: px;
height: px;
```

Comment: Note that you need actual numbers here; `px` isn't a valid value for `height` or `width`, but a value with a number, like `100px`, would be. You can also use percentages (`%`) or `em`; read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height).

Comment: I had intentionally left the value blank so the OP could tailor it to his needs and correct sizing.

Comment: I assumed that's what it was, but wanted to clarify for OP, in case OP doesn't know the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>

  <head>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>

    <title>
      Lovers &amp; Fighters
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="photo">
      <nav>
        <ul id="main">
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Music</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
          <li>Photos</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
        <ul id="social">
          <li>
            <img/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img/>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

And the CSS:

```
.photo{
background-image: url('../images/bandbanner.png');
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```